# copy debug.keystore from a excisting project Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i have an android project.
I have the source code, i have 1 of its version released.
I want to develop this project, but when i try to update old version with my version it says 
Installation failed . Signature verification failed. IS IMPORTANT TO DEVELOP THIS PROJECT.
I want somehow to generate old version signature (debug.keystore). please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you sign a production .APK with your Debug Keystore? That does not sound very good.
The Eclipse debug keystore is located in your */Users/$Username/.android/* folder.
If you have lost your keystore containing the key that you signed with then I believe you have very slim chances of ever being able to update your App again. Unless you can manage to un-delete from the disk with some Disk recovery tools.

Comment: the old version is not compiled in my pc. the only file i have and i can use to try to get the signature are 'the source code' and 'an old version' So with this 2 is there anyway for me to copy their signature, or manipulate data in .APK file so it looks like its the old signature

Comment: The whole purpose of a cryptographic signature key and the keystore is to protect it from being abused like this. The key itself never leaves the keystore, so the key cannot be determined by any of products that has been signed by it.